# Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'FormData'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I m using FormData in angular 5, but it gives error given below.

```
   approvalUser(userId): Observable<any> {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData = formData.append('id',userId); error in this line shows==> "Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'FormData' " 
    return this.http.post<any>(this.url.APPOROVAL_USER,formData);
  }
```

Comment: `formData = formData.append('id',userId);` I don't think you need the assignment, just call the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because FormData.append() does not return anything. So it returns void.

Essential your statement `formData = formData.append('id',userId);` is invalid as you are assigning a `void` type to `FormData` type.

Look at [FormData.append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append).

Remove the assignee and you will be good.

```
approvalUser(userId): Observable<any> {
   let formData = new FormData();
   formData.append('id',userId);

   return this.http.post<any>(this.url.APPOROVAL_USER,formData);
  }
```

Comment: Glad it was helpful. Happy coding.